# What is purpose of t32.exe files in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, exe, executable

```
$ locate *.exe 
/home/ksv/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/t32.exe
/home/ksv/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/t64.exe
/home/ksv/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/w32.exe
/home/ksv/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/w64.exe
```

The command on my ubuntu 16.04 (gnome) shows the windows binaries inside home directories. I want to know for what purpose these files are included?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/distlib/src/1ab472258e2f7e4b6a2d8ce5191bc60a2dc7bf01/PC/?at=default Documented on that page. Tools for Windows, presumably included in the distlib package on all platforms just to not have to pack different versions for each platform.

Comment: you have windows python binary assets in your linux system. get linux version of python source distribution.

Comment: @unixmiah I doubt that's accidental, the [setup script](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/distlib/src/1ab472258e2f7e4b6a2d8ce5191bc60a2dc7bf01/setup.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) copies the *.exe files regardless of the OS as far as I can see.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

When I entered the location, I could not find any exe files there. Its strange but locate command is showing that it contains windows binaries.

Answer (score -1):

When I entered the location, I could not find any exe files there. Its strange but locate command is showing that it contains windows binaries.

Comment: why you posted this as answer?